# Lumen (Laravel) V.S NODE.JS Solutions

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, loopbackjs, lumen

i need to develop an API backend that it should be :

- robust
- high performance
- provides RESTFULL API
- connected to a Mysql storage: i prefer a relation db for the
  complexity
- only backend not also frontend framework

I'm undecided between :

- Lumen : i need only API service because i choose react js as frontend framework.. so i think is better lumen than laravel because i no need frontend
- Nodejs api solution: In this moment searching on the web i found Seals and Loopback as framework for my api backend.

I find discortanti opinions ... some told that php solution as Lumen is not good for performance ( see http://www.infoworld.com/article/2866712/php/php-vs-node-js-an-epic-battle-for-developer-mind-share.html ).... and some one told that in this moment there arent reliable api backend framework in node js: seals is not good for performance and about loopback i found few comment... so i ask you what is the best choiche for performance and robust solution ..

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based so your topic will likely get closed. But I have been using loopback for a couple of years, not for intensive apis, but so far I'm very satisfied with it. Done backend + distributing frontend and it's a nice tool that handles a lot of repetitive tasks, and feels productive to me.

Comment: I prefer Nodejs

Comment: Hi Kali can you tell me the framework that you prefer ?

Comment: Loopback is better than sails ? I've read that sails orm is not so good... about loopback orm ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

﻿If you think about JavaScript for client and server side then you can choose `node.js` with `sails.js` framework which is follow full MVC structure. If you use `sails.js`, you don't need to be expert in `node.js`. It's easy like other PHP framework like `Laravel`. For database you can use `MongoDB`. To work with different types of API include `angular.js` also. So finally your platform dependencies are:

```
1. Node.js (Server Side Coding)
2. Sails.js (For Maintain MVC Structure)
3. Angular.js (For Managing Frontend, HTTP request API etc)
4. MongoDB (For Database)
```

So that you will find out everything require your working development dependency. I think this will help for you.

Thank You :)

Comment: I read bad feedback about sails : https://kev.inburke.com/kevin/dont-use-sails-or-waterline/

Comment: Actually I'm working with a application project since 1 year in Sails.js framework. Application is running perfectly. The updated version of sails.js has great features. I don't supposed to use blueprint in sails.js. Otherwise this is great for working with big and long term/requirement project.

Comment: Hi @Robin and about waterline that is not case sensitive  ? This is a bad issue.... index  is not used in this way... sails team has solved this issue making case sensitive sails ?

Comment: Yes Waterline are still case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Loopback. It has been acquired by IBM so you can expect continued improvement and stability.

Comment: I don't recommend it, it's nightmare to maintain.